# Incremental variable issue in recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, increment

My recursive function is

```
function recursion($vals,$i) //
{
$htm=implode('',file($vals));
echo $i;
if($htm)
{
return $htm;
}
else
{
    echo "\n.................link broken...................\n";
    sleep(10);
    echo "\n.................retrying......................\n";     
    **// return recursion($vals,$i+1);  //case 1
            // return recursion($vals,$i++);    //case 2**
}
}
```

using case 1 is incrementing value of **$i+1** while using **$i++** not increamenting $i value why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because post-increment (`$a++`) operator means

> Returns `$a`, then increments `$a` by one.

Check out [official document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

**Addition:**

And (as @Matt states) pre-increment operator (`++$a`) means increment and then return.

So in your case, you used

```
recursion($i++);
```

Which results in `$i` returning its current value into function call's parameter, *and then* increment itself by one, so `recursion()` will always get the same `$i` because it is incremented *after* it is used as a parameter.

Change to

```
recursion(++$i);
```

Would help.

Comment: And the pre-increment operator (`++$a`) means increment by one and *then* return.